# Prove L*L is invertible if and only if kerL = 0.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L:V \rightarrow W$ and $L^*: W \rightarrow V$, and $L^*L:V \rightarrow V$ on $V$.

Prove Lemma 39.3: 
(a) All eigenvalues of $L^*L$ are real and non negative.
(b) $L^*L$ is invertible if and only if ker$(L) = 0$.

To prove part (a) I set $L^*Lv = \lambda v$ and did $\lambda^* \|v\|^2$ to get to $\|Lv\|^2$ showing that both are real and non nonnegative so $\lambda$ is also real and non negative.

I'm confused on how to approach part (b).

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof for part (a) which does not require the use of a norm: you have $L^*Lv=\lambda v$ (1), so that $v^*L^*L=(L^*Lv)^*=(\lambda v)^*=\overline{\lambda}v^*$ (2). Now multiply (1) on the left by $v^*$ and (2) on the right by $v$. Then you have \begin{equation} \lambda v^* v = v^*L^*Lv=\overline{\lambda}v^*v, \end{equation} and since $v$ is nonzero we must then have $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$, that is, $\lambda$ is real.

For part two, suppose there exists nonzero $v$ so that $Lv=0$, then $L^*Lv=0$ so that $v \in$ ker$(L^*L)$ and hence $L^*L$ is not invertible. Now suppose $L^*L$ is not invertible. Then there is a nonzero $v \in$ ker$(L^*L)$ so that $L^*Lv=0$. Multiply on the left by $v^*$ and we have $v^*L^*Lv=v^*0$, that is, $(Lv)^*Lv=0$ which is only possible if $Lv=0$. So $v \in$ ker$(L)$. This proves part b.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\in\ker A\implies Ax=0\implies A^TAx=0\implies x\in \ker A^TA$$ Conversely, $$x\in \ker A^TA\implies A^TAx=0\implies Ax\in\ker A^T$$ but $$\ker A^T=(\text{im}\;A)^{\perp}$$ so we must have $$Ax=0\implies x\in\ker A$$ Therefore $$\ker A^TA=\ker A$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $L^*L$ is invertible. Then $L^*L$ is one-to-one and onto; therefore, $\text{dim}(\text{ran}(L^*L)) = \text{dim}(V)$. Since $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(L^*L)) + \text{dim}(\text{ran}(L^*L)) = \text{dim}(V)$, we conclude that $\text{ker}(L^*L) = 0$.
For the converse, assume that $\text{ker}(L^*L) = 0$. Since $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(L^*L)) + \text{dim}(\text{ran}(L^*L)) = \text{dim}(V)$, we conclude that $\text{dim}(\text{ran}(L^*L)) = \text{dim}(V)$; therefore, $L^*L$ is one-to-one and onto and hence invertible.

Comment: Is showing the ker(L*L) = 0 the same as showing that just the ker(L) = 0? 
I have to prove just ker(L) = 0.

Comment: Well, if ker(L*L) =0 then L*L is 1-1 and onto. Then L is 1-1, and you may conclude that ker(L) = 0.